# How does one implement FxCop / static analysis on an existing code base

Tags: static-analysis, fxcop, metrics

What are some of the strategies that are used when implementing FxCop / static analysis on existing code bases with existing violations? How can one most effectively reduce the static analysis violations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make liberal use of [SuppressMessage] attribute to begin with. At least at the beginning. Once you get the count to 0 via the attribute, you then put in a rule that new checkins may not introduce FxCop violations.

Visual Studio 2008 has a nice code analysis feature that allows you to ensure that code analysis runs on every build and you can treat warnings as errors. That might slow things down a bit so I recommend setting up a continuous integration server (like CruiseControl.NET) and having it run code analysis on every checkin.

Once you get it under control and aren't introducing new violations with every checkin, start to tackle whole classes of FxCop violations at a time with the goal of removing the SuppressMessageAttributes that you used.

The way to keep track of which ones you really want to keep is to always add a Justification value to the ones you really want to suppress.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your code in a passing style!

Seriously, an old code base will have hundreds of errors - but that's why we have novice/intern programmers. Correcting FxCop violations is a great way to get an overview of the code base and also learn how to write conforming .NET code.

So just bite the bullet, drink lots of caffeine, and just get through it in a couple days!

Answer (score 0):

NDepend [looks like](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/09/23/getting-rid-of-spaghetti-code-in-the-real-world.aspx) it could do what you're after, but I'm not sure if it can be integrated into a CruiseControl.Net automated build, and fail the build if the code doesn't meet the requirements (which is what I'd like to happen).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to FxCop would be to use the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). This tool lets write **Code Rules over C# LINQ Queries** (what we call [CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL)). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own rules is straightforward thanks to the *well-known* C# LINQ syntax.

To keep the number of false-positives low, CQLinq offers the unique capabilities to define what is the set **JustMyCode** through special code queries prefixed with **notmycode**. More explanations about this feature can be found [here](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax.aspx#NotMyCode). Here are for example two *notmycode* default queries:

- [Discard generated and designer Methods from JustMyCode](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Discard_generated_and_designer_Methods_from_JustMyCode.html)
- [Discard generated Types from JustMyCode](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Discard_generated_Types_from_JustMyCode.html)

To keep the number of false-positives low, with CQLinq you can also focus rules result only on code added or code refactored, since a [defined baseline in the past](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Diff.aspx). See the following rule, that detect methods too complex added or refactored since the baseline:

```
warnif count > 0 
from m in Methods
where m.CyclomaticComplexity > 20 &&
      m.WasAdded() || m.CodeWasChanged()
select new { m, m.CyclomaticComplexity }
```

Finally, notice that with NDepend code rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at build process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).