# What are the basic minimum set of Code Analysis rules that you would recommend?

Tags: .net, tfs, code-analysis

What are the basic minimum set of Code Analysis rules that you would recommend for a 200K LOC solution? We're using unit testing but code analysis has been turned off.

Ideally all rules would be turned on by default but I'd like to do this gently and turn on rules in batches so we do not have to deal with everything at once. So, what rules do I start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a [list of rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/08/09/what-rules-do-microsoft-have-turned-on-internally.aspx) turned on by Microsoft as of 2007.

Not really a set of rules but a good advice on turning on Code Analysis on an existing code base can be found in Phil Haack's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009/how-does-one-implement-fxcop-static-analysis-on-an-existing-code-base#29545) to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009/how-does-one-implement-fxcop-static-analysis-on-an-existing-code-base).